# pass variable to scipy curve_fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a dataset using a function:

```
def kel_voigt(x, en2, l2, en3, l3):
  # The first term, 300 should be a variable, from the main
  const = 300 * 1e-6 * math.pi / (2 * math.tan(math.radians(63.3)))
  return const * (((1 - (np.exp(-x / l2))) / en2) +
                  ((1 - (np.exp(-x / l3))) / en3))
```

where, the fitting is called from main as:

```
  for n in range(len(sheets)):
    popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(kel_voigt,
                                       np.array(tl[n]),
                                       np.array(h0l[n]),
                                       maxfev=10000)
```

Now, the problem is, the first term of the variable load (i.e. 300) should be a variable and to be passed from main (it differs with each value of `n` in the main iteration).
From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html, I haven't find out a way to pass the extra parameter to the scipy.optimize.curve_fit().

How I can set the extra variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one additional argument for your fixed variable/constant to your function and wrap this function in each loop iteration:

```py
def kel_voigt(x, fix_var, en2, l2, en3, l3):
  # The first term, 300 should be a variable, from the main
  const = fix_var * 1e-6 * math.pi / (2 * math.tan(math.radians(63.3)))
  return const * (((1 - (np.exp(-x / l2))) / en2) +
                  ((1 - (np.exp(-x / l3))) / en3))

for n in range(len(sheets)):
    # replace 300 with the value in the current iteration
    fun_to_fit = lambda x, en2, l2, en3, l3: kel_voigt(x, 300, en2, l2, en3, l3)
    popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(fun_to_fit,
                                       np.array(tl[n]),
                                       np.array(h0l[n]),
                                       maxfev=10000)
```